# Reactive JDBC Driver for RDS Aurora Serverless

Tags: project-reactor, amazon-aurora, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, aws-aurora-serverless

I have reactive micro service that talks to AWS RDS Aurora serverless. I want to know if there are any JDBC drivers that are non blocking for this like r2dbc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Reactive JDBC Driver for Mysql worked with AWS RDS Aurora Serverless.
https://github.com/mirromutth/r2dbc-mysql